# Writing files on the real external SD card on Android

Tags: android, io, android-sdcard

I have searched everywhere on stackoverflow, there are plenty of similar questions, but the answer always ends up with something that helps write on the internal storage.

I am using the File Browser snippet available here: https://github.com/vaal12/AndroidFileBrowser

After that, I get the path to the directory where I want to create my Folder.

```
try {
    print(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()); //return something like "/storage/sdcard0/"
    String realPath=newDir +"/"+ getString(R.string.folder_name); //returns something like "/storage/extSdCard/..."
    //realPath=realPath.replaceAll("storage", "mnt");
    print(realPath);
    File f = new File(realPath);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        f.mkdirs();
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    print(e.toString());
}
```

This works fine when the chosen directory is on the internal sd card, but nothing happens (not even an `IOException`) when it's on the **removable external sd card**

Comment: Check the return value of mkdirs().

Comment: Your code is incomplete, as it never assigns newDir, so we can't know what the issue is.  In general though, this is *not* how you are supposed to access removable storage on newer Android versions.

Comment: newDir is a String that comes from the snippet I am mentioning above. In my test case, **as mentioned in the code comments**, the result of the picking folder activity is "/storage/extSdcard/Download". I concatenate a "/" and the name of the folder I want to create. If this is "not" how I am supposed to do, please tell me **how**, as this is the purpose of the question.

Comment: As you could imagine, **mkdirs()** is **true** when the location is on the internal storage (what android call the external storage), and **false** when the location is on the removable micro sd card.

Answer (score 0):

There is good description and example about saving onto external storage on the android developer webpage. I think this would help you: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: No, this is not what I am looking for. This writes only on the internal storage, which android calls "external" for an obscur reason.

Comment: You sure ? The documentation says 'Every Android-compatible device supports a shared "external storage" that you can use to save files. This can be a removable storage media (such as an SD card) or an internal (non-removable) storage'

Comment: Well, I guess this definition is ok if you have either one or the other. In my case, I have both, and writing on the additional removable sd card doesn't work, and mkdirs() returns false;

Comment: Actually, it seems to be a problem introduced since KitKat where Android tries to make sure that developers don't write on the secondary external sd card. I am not sure how I can target low prices phones now, but I guess I'll stay on the "external" internal sd card.